# What would the calculated value of the standard deviation of a uniform distribution be?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, normal-distribution

A colleague wants to compare models that use either a Gaussian distribution or a uniform distribution and for other reasons needs the standard devation of these two distributions to be equal.  In R I can do a simulation...

```
sd(runif(100000000))
sd(runif(100000000,min=0,max=2))
```

and see that the calculated standard deviation is likely to be ~.2887 * the range of the uniform distribution.  However, I was wondering if there was an equation that could yield the exact value, and if so, what that formula was.

Comment: What is "not meaningful" about the standard deviation of a uniform distribution? It is a measure of spread for the uniform, just as it is for almost every other distribution. It may not be the best measure of spread, but it is certainly meaningful.

Comment: All I meant was that the standard deviation is not really a parameter that defines or describes the uniform distribution well.  In my mind, the standard deviation refers to the spread of a normal, or near normal distribution.  

Simply because a value is calculable does not mean that it is interesting or meaningful.  For example, I might be able to calculate what rate parameter from an exponential distribution best matches a normal distribution, but to me such a value would not be particularly meaningful because the distribution being described is not actually exponential.

Comment: I can define a uniform distribution with mean 0.5 and standard deviation 1/12. It is perfectly well defined, but it is not the most natural parameterization. There is nothing about standard deviations that implies normality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, the standard deviation of a continous uniform distribution is (max - min) / sqrt(12).

Answer (score 2):

The standard deviation of the continous uniform distribution on the interval [0,1] is 12<sup>-1/2</sup>≈0.288675. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29) lists of it's more properties.

Comment: you mean the standard deviation...

Comment: @shabbychef: You are right. Fixed.